# Is my "import" statement being incorrectly transpiled?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

It is [my understanding](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) that the following two lines are equivalent:

```
const Up = require('write-up').default
```

And...

```
import Up from 'write-up'
```

Both examples should make the default export of the `write-up` module available as `Up`.

Unfortunately, using Babel and Webpack, that's not the behavior I'm seeing.

The first example works just fine. It produces this line:

```
var Up = __webpack_require__(5).default;
```

`Up` is set to the default export of the `write-up` module, which is the behavior I expect.

The second example does *not* work. It produces this:

```
var _writeUp = __webpack_require__(5);

var _writeUp2 = _interopRequireDefault(_writeUp);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Instead of setting `Up` to the default export, `Up` is set to an object containing every single export of the `write-up` module (which includes the `default` field).

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant portion from my Webpack config:

```
{
  test: /.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  query: {
    presets: ['es2015']
  }
}
```

Comment: `import Up from 'write-up';` doesn't always read `.default`, it only reads `.default` if `write-up` was compiled with Babel. If it's just a CommonJS module, `Up` will be the whole `module.exports` object.

Comment: Does your write-up module have an `__esModule` property (or is it an ES6 module itself)?

Comment: In your second example, `Up` is not set at all? Please show the entire code. Notice that any reference to `Up` from ES6 would be transpiled to `_writeUp2.default` in ES5 code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, thank you. `write-up` is a CommonJS module compiled using vanilla TypeScript. If you add an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your comments. That was the issue. `write-up` is a CommonJS module, but I was expecting it to behave like an ES2015 module.

Comment: @start Probably you should let TypeScript compile to ES6 and then let Babel/Webpack do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel-compiled `import` statements have a dual behavior. If the module being imported was compiled from ES6 `export` statements with Babel, then

```
import foo from 'foo';
```

will behave (mostly) like

```
const foo = require('foo').default;
```

but if `foo` was not compiled with Babel, or something that tries to be compatible with Babel, then as far as Babel is concerned, it has no special behavior and is a normal CommonJS module. In that case, which appears to be your case, it will behave like

```
const foo = require('foo');
```

Babel does this so that you can import normal CommonJS modules like

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

where `fs` is a standard Node module and has no `.default` property.

Comment: I can't upvote you, but I can accept the answer. Thank you!